# What is one "content" item in a Wikipedia called?

Tags: terminology

I think that my question can best be explained by an example: In the following Wikipedia entry (I hope "entry" is the right term), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Herring, there are multiple "sections" or "chunks" referred to as "contents" in the page:

[image]

I highlighted a single such "content" with a green border to show that it's not really a paragraph, because it can be comprised of multiple paragraphs.

On the other hand, I don't feel calling it a "section" is right because sections are usually much longer (as in a book or newspaper).

The title above it is simple: "title" or "heading" but what about the content chunk itself? What is the correct or clearest term for that?

Comment: +1 just so you can post the image... you can always just post the link though. :-)

Comment: @Noldorin I did post the link but sometimes a snapshot with colorful highlight makes things clearer. I would have voted you up but I don't have enough points even for that. At least I will be accepting your answer. :) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant the link to the actual image (as well as the page)... to whatever image site you were hosting on.

Comment: I'd call it a **subheading**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia officially calls them *sections* (as can be identified from the tool-tip text of the 'Edit' links by the headers). It's a pretty generic word in any case, so feel free to use it here.

The entirety of the page of the page can be called a (Wikipedia) *entry* (as you suggest), *article*, or indeed *page*. They are all roughly synonymous in this case.

Comment: Indeed, it appears that "section" is what Wikipedia call that "chunk". I am open for additional suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, and if I came across the term, I would consider it perfectly normal. :-) Calling it a "part" or "division" would also be acceptable in my view. Glad it helped, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not happy with Wikipedia's own term, *section*, you might prefer *segment.*

Comment: What's wrong with "chapter"?

Comment: @Nemo - Given that the OP's objection to 'section' was "On the other hand, I don't feel calling it a "section" is right because sections are usually much longer (as in a book or newspaper)", I think you can figure out the answer to your own question.